# loopj http library on Android : callback when activity is in background

Tags: android, crash, lifecycle, loopj

Neither the documentation, nor stackoverflow has an answer to the below question.

I am using loopj library for HTTP Get requests in my Android App. In my `onSuccess()` callback, I am updating a `TextView` with the results.

I was curious as to what happens if my `Activity` is not in front of `Activity` stack when the callback happens, (ex: am receiving a call).  I expected it to crash.  Strangely, it did not crash and also, the update to the `TextView` had happened when I went back to the `Activity`?

How is this possible ?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem: How can an update to Textview work when my activity is in background?

Comment: If there's a crash, post the stacktrace/LogCat

Comment: @Sufian: No crash. The question is should'nt it crash ?  I am writing to an textview of an activity which is currently in background?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't crash because the `Activity` was not destroyed. However, it's not recommended to update UI components in a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

If you really need to, you can store the results in a field and or at a minimum, put a check like this:

```
if(myTextView != null)
    myTextView.setText("results here");
```

Comment: @user2460477 if this answer helps, please marks this as correct answer by clicking that tick mark next to the answer.